# Regex for sets of numbers in a string

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working in snowflake and need to extract two sets of numbers from a string in a query.

```
"purchase_id:12345678 charge_id:987654321"
```

I need to extract each set of numbers individually `12345678` and `987654321` in their own columns. So far I've got

```
REGEXP_REPLACE("purchase_id:12345678 charge_id:987654321", '[^[:digit:]]', ' '),
```

which returns `12345678 987654321`. I have almost no experience with regex so have been struggling to find solutions and apply them to my specific case (or know if I'm even on the correct solution path).

Both sets of digits also have varying length (7-9 digits for each).

Please let me know if there's additional info needed, thanks!

Comment: Why are you using REGEXP_REPLACE  rather than REGEXP_SUBSTR?

Comment: @gelfiusm I couldn't get REGEXP_SUBSTR() to work as expected and made more progress with REPLACE. I'm sure it was a syntax error on my part though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
select
REGEXP_SUBSTR('purchase_id:123456 charge_id:987654321', '\\d+', 1, 1) as purchase_id,
REGEXP_SUBSTR('purchase_id:123456 charge_id:987654321', '\\d+', 1, 2) as charge_id
from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

see if this works:

```
select col
       ,SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'purchase_id:[0-9]*'),':','2') as purchase_id
       ,SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'charge_id:[0-9]*'),':','2') as purchase_id
from (select 'purchase_id:12345678 charge_id:987654321' as col )
```

Comment: This works too! I'm not sure of the nuances between yours and Brock's solution, but thank you!